# jQuery File Upload Plugin - multiple image resolutions

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload

I am using jQuery File Upload plugin to upload and resize images in client's browser. However, when I attempt to generate multiple image resolutions (generate multiple image versions and upload each to a server), I get images with only the resolution specified in the last two *resizeImage* queries in the *processQueue*. I have used code suggested in the [wiki](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Upload-multiple-resolutions-of-one-image-with-multiple-resize-options) of the plugin. My code is as follows:

```
//code for duplicating the image - from wiki of the upload plugin
$.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.processActions.duplicateImage = function (data, options) {
    if (data.canvas) {
        data.files.push(data.files[data.index]);
    }
    return data;
};

$('.fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    maxChunkSize: 500000,
    maxFileSize: 33554432,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    loadImageMaxFileSize: 33554432,

    disableImagePreview: true,

    disableImageResize: false,
    disableImageMetaDataSave: true,

    //the processQueue code, as suggested in the wiki of the plugin
    processQueue: [
        {
            action: 'loadImage',
            fileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
            maxFileSize: 33554432
        },
        {
            action: 'resizeImage',
            maxWidth: 3000,
            maxHeight: 3000
        },
        {action: 'saveImage'},
        {action: 'duplicateImage'},
        {
            action: 'resizeImage',
            maxWidth: 1280,
            maxHeight: 1280
        },
        {action: 'saveImage'},
        {action: 'duplicateImage'},
        {
            action: 'resizeImage',
            maxWidth: 1024,
            maxHeight: 1024
        },
        {action: 'saveImage'}
    ],

    done: function (e, data) {
        //handling of finished upload
    })
    .bind('fileuploadadded', function (e, data) {
            data.submit();
    })
})
```

When scaling down image with resolution of 6000x4000 with this code, the **expected result** would be **3** images

1. image with resolution 3000x2000
2. image with resolution 1280x853
3. image with resolution 1024x683

However, I get **4** images instead

1. image with resolution 1024x683
2. image with resolution 1024x683
3. image with resolution **1280x853**
4. image with resolution 1024x683

Which seems very strange to me. I guess the problem is in the *duplicateImage* function, but I have no idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on same thing. Mine has worked correctly, it created 3 different versions., I simple did not write any binding function like you did in the end:

```
).bind('fileuploadadded', function (e, data) {
   data.submit();
})
```

but I added `$.blueimp.fileupload::options.add.call this, e, data` to my `add:` function, along with

```
$.blueimp.fileupload::processActions.duplicateImage = (data, options) ->
  if data.canvas
    data.files.push data.files[data.index]
  data
```

before the `fileupload` function on form element.